# How to update a jQuery object stored in a variable after DOM change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I normally store my jQuery objects in variables to avoid having the selector written all over the place.

When I change the DOM, I would like to make the object update itself. Dropping unused references and getting updated with the new ones. How can I do this? Ideally I want to do something with the following logic:

```
var test = $('div.bar');
console.log(test);
>> [<div class="bar" id="b1"></div>, <div class="bar" id="b2"></div>]

$('#b2').remove();
console.log(test);
>> [<div class="bar" id="b1"></div>, <div class="bar" id="b2"></div>]

test.update();
console.log(test);
>> [<div class="bar" id="b1"></div>]

$('body').append('<div class="bar" id="b3"></div>');
console.log(test);
>> [<div class="bar" id="b1"></div>]

test.update();
console.log(test);
>> [<div class="bar" id="b1"></div>, <div class="bar" id="b3"></div>]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This plugin](https://github.com/fmsf/jQuery-obj-update) solves that problem:

```
(function ( $ ) {
  $.fn.update = function(){
    var newElements = $(this.selector),i;    
    for(i=0;i<newElements.length;i++){
      this[i] = newElements[i];
    }
    for(;i<this.length;i++){
      this[i] = undefined;
    }
    this.length = newElements.length;
    return this;
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Just add it to your code and do:

```
var $foo = $("div.bar"); // selects all "div.bar"
(... many dom modifications ...)
$foo.update();
```

Comment: To those down voting can anyone explain why this is a bad approach to updating the object? Or am I just getting down voted because I'm sharing something you don't consider to be useful? (note sharing useful stuff in Q&A style is encouraged by stackexchange)

Comment: I do not understand the downvotes, neither on the original question nor on your answer.  Downvotes without comments sucks.

Comment: It's a good question and it doesn't hurt anybody. I think you only need `return $(this.selector)`.

Comment: @undefined I had thought about that, but if the user had attached anything to the variable, the new object would overwrite everything. (i.e: $foo.something = '12345'). This way it only overwrites the DOM references themselves. do you agree?

Comment: @fmsf In that case I agree.

Comment: `this.selector` will only work when no other methods (such as `.find`, `.children`, etc) have been used to select the elements.

Comment: @FelixKling that's a good point, when I designed this I was thinking of the use case with selectors, so I completely forgot about those. Tks

Comment: Np... I honestly don't know how this could be solved... you could test whether each node is still part of the tree (buy traversing up as far as possible, until `body` (e.g. using `.closest`)) but that does not seem to be very efficient. Btw. since `this` is an object, `delete this[i]` might be better than `this[i] = undefined`.